# Trying to install imapsync on Kali Linux

Tags: kali-linux, imapsync

I'm trying to install the imapsync package on my Kali Linux, by following the steps described in this guide: https://tecadmin.net/use-imapsync-on-ubuntu/

However, at the final step where I am supposed to actually run the installer of for the imapsync, by executing the following command: **

> $ sudo make install

** I received the following message:

**

```
What you have to do before using imapsync:
Install Perl module Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA
Install Perl module Dist::CheckConflicts
Install Perl module IO::Socket::INET6
Install Perl module IO::Tee
Install Perl module JSON::WebToken::Crypt::RSA
Install Perl module LWP::UserAgent
Install Perl module PAR::Packer
Install Perl module Regexp::Common
Install Perl module Sys::MemInfo
Install Perl module Term::ReadKey
Install Perl module Test::Pod
Install Perl module Unicode::String
```

**

**

```
Here is a cpanm command to install missing Perl modules:
cpanm Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA Dist::CheckConflicts IO::Socket::INET6 IO::Tee JSON::WebToken::Crypt::RSA LWP::UserAgent PAR::Packer Regexp::Common Sys::MemInfo Term::ReadKey Test::Pod Unicode::String
```

**

I have tried several time to run the command showed at the end, however, no luck, since it still shows that I have the libraries missing.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Regards,

Comment: Have you tried installing the libraries? Also, Kali Linux is a very specific-purpose distro that is not designed to be easy or accessible. Unless you're already very familiar with Linux, how it works, and how to use it, you should no be trying to use Kali.

Comment: I disregard the fact that I might use the "imapsync" command once connected to a server, what I was thinking was that I could have it install locally on my PC and run it through the user "~$" directly. 

Otherwise, I'm aware that Kali Linux is a specific distribution of Linux for security purposes etc. As of now I was able to switch to Ubuntu 18.03 - which I managed to install through Windows store and was able to properly use the "imapsync" once connected to a server.

Appreciate your response, music2myear!

Comment: Are you saying you found the issue that caused the problem?

Comment: I tried to run the installation on Ubuntu and this time, I got a better result then having it on Kali, since it only required a couple of Perl libraries:

What you have to do before using imapsync:
Install Perl module Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA
Install Perl module JSON::WebToken::Crypt::RSA

However, I tried "cpanm Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA --force" in order to get the libraries and met the following error:

"Can't write to cpanm home '/home/slick/.cpanm': You should fix it with chown/chmod first." I then tried: "sudo chmod 0755 -R .cpanm/" but still no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: New information needs to be added to the question itself, not placed in comments. Use the EDIT button to do this. One of the key factors of Kali Linux is that it does NOT include many libraries present in other distros. You need to be very comfortable in Linux in general before you should attempt to delve into Kali. Kali is a testing and research tool version, not a "daily driver" or "desktop replacement" distro.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me

Comment: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4640/what-should-we-do-about-kali-linux-questions

Comment: I appreciated the provided information ... noted :)